# Rails: How to perform callbacks on a model that is not updated but is related to updated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

to KIS I have two models: `Reservations` and `Containers`.

```
 Container 
 has_many :reservations

 Reservation
 belongs_to :container
```

When I update a reservation I also want to perform call backs on the respective Container.

What is a good way to do this?

Should I be using nested rest routes, put the container logic in the Reservation model, or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has an option called `touch`.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :container, :touch => true
end
```

Rails updates the `updated_at` field of the `Container` object when ever `Reservation` object changes. If you have any callbacks in `Container` class they will be invoked when `Reservation` object changes.

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  after_update :reservation_change

  def reservation_change
    # handle the updates..
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that touch no longer calls the validations or callbacks in Rails 3.